# connect and quit message on main channel

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want  to send message to users if some new person is joining or user is quiting the chat.
i don't really know where to start to get this function work.

On disconnect message 'This users is gone' to all On Connect "user is connected to the chatbox"

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    nicknames = [];

server.listen(8000);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1){
            callback(false);
        } else{
            callback(true);
            socket.nickname = data;
            nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
            updateNicknames();
        }
    });

    function updateNicknames(){
        io.sockets.emit('usernames', nicknames);
    }

    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', {msg: data, nick: socket.nickname});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        if(!socket.nickname) return;
        nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickname), 1);
        updateNicknames();      

    });


})
```

;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the broadcast function. This will broadcast to every other socket except the one that send the broadcast.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    socket.broadcast.emit('leave',{name:name});
});



socket.on('leave', function (msg) {
    //Add msg that msg.name is leaving
});
```

Comment: How do i trigger it on join or quit ?

Comment: for join, inside the onconnection

Comment: and for quit, inside the disconnect

Comment: i edited my post, when disconnect you broadcast an event, this event is catch by all other user who can show that someone left

Comment: Thanks you very much i learned the basic of serverside to client now littlebit more